# How to call Edittext onEditorAction from xml using data binding

Tags: android, data-binding

like the below code

```
<data>
    <variable
      name="listener"
      type="android.view.View.OnClickListener" />
</data>


<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android: text="@ {user.firstName}"
     android:onClick="@{listener::onClick}"/>
```

I'm wanted to call the editorAction from XML, it is possible to perform it through xml ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Create interface

```
interface CustomOnEditorActionListener {
    fun onEditorAction()
}
```

2.BindingAdapter

```
@BindingAdapter("app:customOnEditorActionListener")
fun setCustomOnEditorActionListener(view: TextView, listener: CustomOnEditorActionListener?) {
    if (listener == null) {
        view.setOnEditorActionListener(null)
    } else {
        view.setOnEditorActionListener(object : TextView.OnEditorActionListener {
            override fun onEditorAction(v: TextView?, actionId: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
                listener.onEditorAction()
                return false
            }
        })
    }
}
```

3.in XML. viewModel implemented interface CustomOnEditorActionListener

```
    ...
<variable
name="viewModel"
type="nl.login.LoginViewModel" />

    ...
<EditText
android:id="@+id/password_edit"
app:customOnEditorActionListener="@{viewModel}"
    ...
```